# How to change the image src in my html so I can create other CSS styles for handheld or mobile devices using the CSS

Tags: css, image, src

This is the code for the links on one of my pages

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Savings Calculator Page</title>
<link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="keywords" content="spray foam insulation, foam insulation, insulation,   energy savings, energy cost reduction, savings, spray insulation" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="calculator1"> </div>
<div id="calculator2"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/images/images/calculator_02.jpg" width="179" height="69" border="0" alt="Home button"/></a> </div>
<div id="calculator3"> <a href="services.html"><img src="images/images/images/calculator_03.jpg" width="125" height="69" border="0" alt="Services button"/></a></div>
<div id="calculator4"><a href="calculator.html"><img src="images/images/images/calculator_04.jpg" width="267" height="69" border="0" alt="Savings Calculator button"/></a> </div>
<div id="calculator5"><a href="aboutUs.html"><img src="images/images/images/calculator_05.jpg" width="178" height="69" border="0" alt="About Us button"/></a> </div>
<div id="calculator6"><a href="contactUs.html"><img src="images/images/images/calculator_06.jpg" width="211" height="69" border="0" alt="Contact Us button"/></a> </div>
<div id="calculator7"> </div>
<form id="calc" name="calc" method="post" action="" >  
<div id="calculator8"> </div>
<div id="calculator9"><input type="text" id="textbox1_id" class="box1" /> </div>
<div id="calculator10"> </div>
<div id="calculator11"> </div>
<div id="calculator12"> </div>
<div id="calculator13"><input type="text"  id="textbox2_id" class="box2" /> </div>
<div id="calculator14"> </div>
<div id="calculator15"> </div>
<div id="calculator16"> </div>
<div id="calculator17"><input type="button" class="button" value="" onclick="calculate()" /></div>
<div id="calculator18"> </div>
<div id="calculator19"> </div>
<div id="calculator20"> </div>
<div id="calculator21"><input type="text"    id="textbox3_id" class="box3"  readonly="readonly" value="" />   </div>
<div id="calculator22"> </div>
</form>
<div id="calculator23"> </div>
<div id="calculator24"> 
<div id="footer1"> </div>
<div id="footer2"> </div>
<div id="footer3"> <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
  src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" width="88" height="31" border="0" /></a> </div>
<div id="footer4"> </div>
<div id="footer5">    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
    <img src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
        alt="Valid CSS!" border="0" style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px" />
</a> </div>
<div id="footer6"> </div>
<div id="footer7"> </div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I really want to do is source the image with CSS, remember!!!! they have to stay links to the other pages. If there are other ways to do this then I am open to suggestion...a little of javascript, some PHP, and my Dreamweaver is what I am using...if one can do this with any of these it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can do. First drop all height, width, border attributes on your image tags. These should be done in css. I recommend adding a class to the images instead of targeting an element in the style sheet.

Since you image height at width are now controlled in css you can set media queries to display image sizes based on the users screen.

Here is an example:

```
#container img{
    width: auto;
    height: 69px;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
}
```

You should be able to take it from there. Good luck!